# Easiest way to create objects in ios

Tags: objective-c, ios

Does iOS support something like

```
s = { x:3,y:5 , o:{x:0,y:1}}
```

like in Javascript?

Or what is the best way to use something like this in iOS?

Comment: Why do you need a short way of doing this? If you abhor verbosity, I would suggest you being writing in a language other than Objective-C.

Comment: actually its not the shortest, looking for best way of doing it.

Comment: Thanks for all answers, it looks like easiest way is to do it with dictionary obj.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A literal translation would be :

```
NSDictionary *s = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                        [NSNumber numberWithInt:3], @"x",
                        [NSNumber numberWithInt:5], @"y",
                        [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                 [NSNumber numberWithInt:0], @"x",
                                 [NSNumber numberWithInt:1], @"y",
                                  nil ], @"o",
                        nil  ];
```

But literal translations, even in programming languages, are not best.  It all depends on the context and what you need to accomplish.  There's probably less code required depending on what you need.

---

**EDIT**:  There's now a new [literal syntax](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/FoundationTypesandCollections/FoundationTypesandCollections.html) allowing to shrink this code further:

```
NSDictionary *s = @{ @"x": @3
                   , @"y": @5
                   , @"o": @{ @"x": @0, @"y": @1}
                   };
```

This syntax implicitely creates the NSDictionary & NSNumber objects.

Answer (score 3):

No, there is no shortcut syntax for dicts in Objective-C. You have to do it manually.

Answer (score 2):

It depends exactly what type of object you mean. There really isn't a generic answer here.

If you're referring to an NSDictionary for example, you could use

[`+ (id)dictionaryWithObjects:(NSArray *)objects forKeys:(NSArray *)keys`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsdictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSDictionary/dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys%3a)

or any of the variants documented on the same page.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is create a JSON string and then use a JSON framework to generate the corresponding NSArray/NSDictionary structure. This would approach what you are trying to do, but not quite there... Then you can describe your object structure with something like this:

```
{"x": 3, "y" : 5, "o" : {"x": 0, "y" : 1}}
```

Main limitation is that you won't have numeric types out of the box, but you can use NSNumber, NSScanner and so on to get them.

Answer (score 1):

You could write a setter or helper method that could take a string in the above format, syntax check it, parse it, and use the string fields to create or modify an NSDictionary for you automatically from a one line call.

But it's not a built function of Obj C or the NSFoundation frameworks.  Some JSON Category additions might do something like this though.

Answer (score 0):

No, it does not support. But i am sorry, im not fammiliar with JS.

To creat a obj in iOS you do the following:

```
ObjName *objVar;
```

then you set its properties:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) ObjName *objVar;
```

then you syntesize it in the .m

```
@syntesize objVar;
```

and the you alloc it and init it in the desired method.

Comment: if its a local obj you just do ObjName *objVar = [[ObjName alloc] init];